# The program crashes with the following and "lldb" in the debugger - Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, lldb

this is a code for a program that behaves like this : When the user presses the button , the UIImage called " The Character" goes up (It changes its y axis). But when I run the program , it doesn't crash but when I press the button called "characterGoesUp" , the program crashes and I get the following  in the debugger : "lldb".Why?
Code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var TheCharacter: UIImageView!

@IBAction func characterGoesUp(_ sender: Any) {
    let xPos = TheCharacter.frame.origin.x

    let yPos = TheCharacter.frame.origin.y - 225

    let heightCharacter = TheCharacter.frame.size.height
    let widthCharacter = TheCharacter.frame.size.width

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.TheCharacter.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: widthCharacter, height: heightCharacter)
    }) { (finished) in

    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


}
```

Xcode version : 9.3

EDIT:
The error is this : 
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Attach the crash log

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the imageView `TheCharacter` is not properly connected to IB , and because of `!`

```
@IBOutlet weak var TheCharacter: UIImageView!
```

in declaration it crashes as it's nil

//

Open the assistant editor and  drag from the image to the ViewController's imageView

[image]

Comment: How can I fix that?